# how to configure fedora nic to be up with no IP

Tags: linux, networking, configuration

I am building an IDS box with a dedicated sniffer nic which should have no IP.
I can't seem to get the system to come up with no IP on the nic, it either uses DHCP or takes the same IP as the first NIC to come up (eth0 = normal, eth1 = sniffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

```
 DEVICE=eth1
 USERCTL=no
 ONBOOT=yes
```

Comment: And test with '/etc/init.d/networking restart' (or maybe just network).

Comment: Thats what I had, but the server isn't taking it. thanks though

Comment: Try adding BOOTPROTO=none

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that NetworkManager was running, which conflicted with the network service, so it inconsistently tried to configure the interfaces (i have no idea where NetworkManager stores its configs)

Solution was to disable the NetworkManger service completely (services + chkconfig off) and then it all started working correctly.

Thanks for your input, i did miss a few things you guys came up with in my initial ifcfg's.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the info from another interface (eth0) into the eth1 file, set it to use a static IP, and make the IP 0.0.0.0 with a netmask of 255.255.255.255.  That should do what you want.